# How to convert R plot or ggplot2 to base64 string?

Tags: r, ggplot2, base64

Lets say I have this code (where x and y are placeholders):

```
  df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(2,3,4,5,6))
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

Is there any way to convert the plot into a base64 string? I am going to send it back with other data through plumber to display on a webpage.

I am open to using a different plotting function or library if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the ggplot:

```
ggsave("myggplot.png", plot)
```

Then use the `base64enc` package as follows:

```
base64enc::dataURI(file = "myggplot.png", mime = "image/png")
```